# 16.04 with nouevau driver does not let me set native resolution for monitor to 2560x1080

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution

I have an LG extra wide screen monitor with a 2560x1080 native resolution, however with ubuntu I can not select this resolution with an nvidia display adapter. It does work with a AMD adapter on my other computer. However opensuse (tumbleweed) with the same type of driver sees it with no problem on the same computer with the nvidia adapter. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Using the nouveau in 16.04 seems not to support that resolution, however I installed ubuntu 16.10 beta 2 and the resolution solved itself.